# Android internal test not compatible with my device

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility, google-play-console

I published my app on Google Play as an internal test. Added the testers emails to the list of testers and sent them the opt-in URL to download the app.

They managed to download the app from Google Play without any problems.

I tried downloading the app with my OnePlus One but I get "This app is incompatible with your device." in Google Play, even though the phone is listed as compatible in Google Play Console.

[image]

I am connected to the Play Store using an account that I added in the testers list and is different from my dev account.

How can I detect where the compatibility problem comes from?

Here's my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danilecx.oofmusicplayer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.danilecx.oofmusicplayer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_oof"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_oof_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**: Installation works on BlueStacks but not on Nox or my phone(OnePlus One).

Comment: It's not enough to add someone to the list of testers, they need to follow the link that is sent to them by email, and accept to receive apps from this track. Then, wait for a bit until things propagate.

Comment: The app has been published for  more than 24h. I followed the link and I have access to the Google Play page of my app. I guess I wouldn't have access to it if I wasn't part of the testers.

Comment: I work on Play and have had a look at your app. Something slightly weird is going on. On StackOverflow I can't be sure you are actually the app developer. Could you please contact Play console support via the help menu in the Play console? When you contact them could you ask them to attach your report to b/126134874 please. Your manifest and gradle look ok.

Comment: @NickFortescue Thanks for the answer. I sent a mail to Google Play developer support 2-3 days ago but they didn't respond yet. Is there any other way I can prove to you than I am the real developper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself and I though I would share it.

The problem was not coming from my code but from my OnePlus One.

After changing the fingerprint in build.prop to "ro.build.fingerprint=oneplus/bacon/A0001:4.4.4/KTU84Q/XNPH38R:user/release-keys", it worked !

For more info go to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/avnpjm/apps_missing_from_playstore/). Hope this helps !

Comment: I can't believe but it helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while building for a Maui Application. What I had to do is that I updated my phone's Google Play Service in order for me to install it as an internal tester. Make sure to restart the phone after the update